# Error in par(bg = "seashell") : could not find function "par"

Tags: r, initialization

I´ve put `par(bg = "seashell")` in "Rprofile.site" file and got the message:

> `Error in par(bg = "seashell") : could not find function "par"`.

Then I put `library(graphics)` before it and that error stopped.
But now, RStudio opens these windows:

[image: Graphics Device Window]

How can I set `par(bg)` at startup?

Comment: @NelsonGon I found a workaround. Should I post an answer or edit the question? tks

Comment: You can post it as an answer and accept it later.